# how can i convert this to left outer join?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a code that is working and what I wanted is to convert it into a left outer join. Here's the code:

```
SELECT 
  dept_code "Dept Code", 
  INITCAP(dept_name) "Dept Name", 
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE 
        dept_dept_code = DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_CODE
        AND
        resign_date IS NULL
   ) "Emp Count"
FROM 
   DEPARTMENTS;
```

I tried this, but the output isn't the same:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
         dept.dept_code "Dept Code",
         INITCAP (dept.dept_name) "Dept Name",
         COUNT (empl.dept_dept_code) "Emp Count"
    FROM DEPARTMENTS dept
         LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES empl
            ON (dept.DEPT_CODE = empl.dept_dept_code
                AND empl.resign_date IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY dept.dept_code, dept.dept_name
```

Comment: What's missing? Nothing, probably, but you might want to move `AND empl.resign_date IS NOT NULL` out of JOIN and put it into the WHERE clause.

Comment: if i do that, the departments with 0 employees row wont show. i need to show departments without employees.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you haven't explained why you aren't happy with your own solution - what does it do wrong?

Comment: its my first time asking a question here. im sorry guys :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
  SELECT d.dept_code "Dept Code",
         INITCAP (d.dept_name) "Dept Name",
         COUNT (e.dept_dept_code) "Emp Count"
    FROM SS_DEPARTMENTS d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ss_empliyees e
            ON e.dept_dept_code = d.dept_code AND e.resign_date IS NULL
GROUP BY d.dept_code, INITCAP (d.dept_name);
```

Comment: Also move the `e.resign_date IS NULL` condition into the `ON` clause.